Windows - can't install MS Visual C++ Redistributable
I want to install software including Visual Studio, however, there is on issue -
the Visual C++ component doesn't install properly, giving error.
What I did:
I ran the uninstaller tool from MS
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/9/7E9188C0-2511-4B01-8B4E-0A641EC2F600/MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab
and uninstalled all VC++ Redistributable (including runtime) instances for x86 and x64,
so there is absolutely no trace of Visual C++
Also cleaned the registry, rebooted.  Many times.
Then I try to install the latest version from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-160
x86 installs fine, but x64 always gives error no matter what. Error is:
"The older version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2022 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.38. cannot be removed"
and at the end:
"0x80070643 Fatal error during installation"
The log file is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5AAoXs5bzroyt8D7XcRVfhIX2XByVw4/view?usp=sharing
Because of this, Visual Studio doesn't install properly either (at the end it gives warning)
Question is how can I install this component properly.

Try run as admin and update the windows installer

Done that too.  I always run as admin.

I'm unable to open this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5AAoXs5bzroyt8D7XcRVfhIX2XByVw4/view?usp=sharing
. Could you please provide a screenshot or copy the essential information here?

It's a shared file in Google Drive

I made the log file available for download here too:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ezn75dj8ajwrzuq/VC_Redist_amd64_202405022128.log/file

Can you get the related key in the register? And have you tested the methods below?

1, Make sure you remove the correct registry item.
Try to press Win+R, type and run regedit, click Edit => Find, search for key word: 14.38, click Find Next button.
If you can find the related Registry keys, try to rename or delete the key(Note: make sure to backup the Registry before you try to modify it).
How to back up and restore the registry in Windows
Back up the below registry item and remove the entire item:

2, Rename some folders related to Visual Studio.
I also doubt that the old version of the package or some corresponding files still exist on your machine. I would suggest you also try to remove some cache files/folders, such as:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
%programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages

Also rename the %Temp% folder, after the above steps restart the computer and test again.
3, Update Windows.
To avoid windows issue, try update windows and make sure there is no update issue.

By the way, since you use the troubleshooter tool, could you please share the screenshot about what you detected to the list.
